# How to move IIS Express config file location

Tags: iis-express

`applicationHost.config` file for my local IISExpress on my new work laptop is for some reason located on a network drive. Is there any way how can I move this to a more usual location under `My Documents` folder on a local drive? I'm not always connected to my workplace network and it is causing me some troubles especially when working with apps that have virtual directories defined.
My system is Windows 7, IIS Express 8.
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just configure offline files support? I presume it's on the network drive because an entire part of your profile has been redirected to a network drive by your IT department?

Comment: @Damien - you are right, thanks. This is my first company laptop so I'm still new to things like offline files.